# Performing join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models

`Company`, which `has_many` customers and
`Customer`, which `belongs_to` a company

I want to retrieve a relation where each row looks something like:

```
[company.name, count(customers)]
```

where the last column is the amount of customers under a company.

```
Company(id: integer, name: string)

Customer(id: integer, name: string, company_id: integer)
```

Much appreciated, thanks

Comment: wish you to do it with a single query?

Comment: can you pls share table structures/column names?

Comment: updated post with columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you issue this:

```
Customer.count(group: company_id)
```

it should return a `hash` with `company_id` as keys, and counted customers as values.
Then you can try this:

```
Company.joins(:customers).select("name, count(*)").all
```

Comment: @Tarlen please, try both and provide the result query for the last approach.

Answer (score 0):

smth like that would help

```
select company.id, company.name, count(*)
from   company join customer on customer.company_id = company.id
group by compamy.id, company.name
```

Comment: awesome, but how would it look if i used active record?